# Proving a probability density function with an unknown parameter

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Given the function $f_\theta$ with the parameters $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$:
>
> $$f_\theta(x)=\begin{cases}a(b+\theta x^3)&\text{for }-1 \leq x \leq 1\\
> 0&\text{otherwise }\\
> \end{cases}$$
> Where $\theta \in [-1, 1]$ is an unknown parameter.
>
> Find all pairs $(a, b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that for all $\theta \in [-1, 1]$, $f_\theta$ is a density function.

First we know that $$\int_{-∞}^∞ {f_\theta(x) \text{ }dx = 1}$$

$$\Rightarrow \int_{-∞}^∞ {f_\theta(x) \text{ }dx =} { \int_{-1}^1 {a(b+\theta x^3) \text{ } dx} } = 2ab$$

Now we have

$$a = \dfrac{1}{2b}$$

Secondly, we have to show that

$$f_\theta(x) \geq 0,  \text{ } \forall x, \theta \in [-1, 1] $$

$$\Leftrightarrow a(b+\theta x^3) \geq 0,  \text{ } \forall x, \theta \in [-1, 1] $$

---

Here is where I get stuck. My idea was to use separate cases to prove the inequality, but how am I supposed to know which values $a$ and $b$ take? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where does the function take its maximum and minimum values?

Comment: @Gregory ok, so we have to consider two cases at $x = 0$ and $x \neq 0$, how do I continue from there? How can I evaluate the function with two unknowns $a, b$?

Comment: Actually, depending on the sign of $\theta$ the max (min) are at the endpoints.

Comment: Note also that $a = 1/(2b)$ as you have stated and so you can split into two cases, where $b > 0$ and $b < 0$. You should then be able to find conditions on $b$ such that $f$ is everywhere nonnegative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you showed that $2ab = 1$, you can get rid of $a$ altogether:

$$a\left(b+\theta x^3\right) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\theta}{2b}x^3.$$

So, you need

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\theta}{2b}x^3 \geq -\frac{1}{2} \qquad &\Rightarrow& \qquad \frac{\theta}{b}x^3 \geq -1\\
&\Rightarrow & \qquad \frac{\alpha}{b} \geq -1,
\end{eqnarray*}

where $\alpha = \theta x^3$ is also bounded between $\left[-1,1\right]$. Any $b\geq 1$ or $b \leq -1$ should do the job.

Comment: This is not good enough, you can obtain tighter bounds.

Comment: Also it is just missing answers. Take $b = -2$, $a = -1/4$ and $\theta = 0$. This is a valid pdf, but not captured in your answer.

Comment: But it has to hold for _all_ $\theta$, right? All we can say for sure is that $\alpha \in \left[-1,1\right]$, but we need $\frac{\alpha}{b} \geq -1$ for all $\alpha$ in that range.

Comment: Then certainly $b \le -1$ is valid as well?

Comment: You are right though, I missed the for all, so the bounds are as good as you can have, but you are missing the negative solutions.

Comment: Yes, you are right as well. Will edit.